# Window function is not supported in order by clauses

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I am using Amazon Redshift to query the data. I want to select the top 4 products that generated most revenue within each quarter group. I used windows function to calculate the sum value of revenues per product within a quarter then use another window function to pick up the top 4 items in each group. Here is my code:

```
SELECT  es.itemid,es.total_Revenue,es.quarter
FROM (         
      SELECT  SALE_CET.itemid
      --get total revenue per quarter
             ,SUM(SALE_CET.totalseller) OVER
                    (PARTITION BY  SALE_CET.itemid,SALE_CET.quarter) AS total_Revenue
             ,SALE_CET.quarter
      --Rank the data by total revenue within each group 
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                    (PARTITION BY  SALE_CET.quarter ORDER BY total_Revenue DESC
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS ra
      FROM SALE_CET) es
WHERE es.ra <=4
```

I know may be we could not use aggregate value in an order-by clause. But if I want to order the records by its total revenue per item per quarter, how I can implement it?

Thanks for your help.

The SALE_CET table is a tempary table created from CTE. 
The Create table command will be like:

```
WITH SALE_CET (userid,itemid, totalseller,year,month,quarter,dayofyear) AS 
    ( SELECT  userid 
             ,itemid
             ,itemprice*orderqty AS TotalSeller
             ,DATEPART (year, orderdatetime) AS year
             ,DATEPART (month, orderdatetime) AS month
             ,DATEPART (quarter, orderdatetime) AS quarter
             ,DATEPART (dayofyear, orderdatetime) AS dayofyear           
      FROM   sales)
```

Comment: Please provide the `create table` that you used to create `SALE_CET`.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error if so what is it?  You should be able to to just add ORDER BY es.total_Revenue to the end of the query.  That is an outer select on a derived table so I don't see why that wouldn't work

Comment: @Matt, Hi matt, thanks for your suggestion. by using "ORDER BY  quarter, total_Revenue DESC" in the outer query, it can display all the items with the expected order. But to select top 4 items in each category(here is quarter), it seems we have to use window function like rank() over

Comment: Finally, I fixed it by creating a CTE and do aggregation in it. Then use the window function to rand the sum value.

Answer (score 0):

If you add another ROW_NUMBER() or DENSE_RANK() ranked by your revenue descending in your sub query then you should be able to access that value in the order by of the outer query.

Something like below. This is the general idea.

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
           itemid, 
           total_Revenue,
           quarter
           ra,
           RevenueByItemThenByQuarter=DENSE_RANK() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY  SALE_CTE2,ietemid,SALE_CET2.quarter ORDER BY SALE_CTE2.total_Revenue DESC
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  SALE_CET.itemid
                  --get total revenue per quarter
                         ,SUM(SALE_CET.totalseller) OVER
                                (PARTITION BY  SALE_CET.itemid,SALE_CET.quarter) AS total_Revenue
                         ,SALE_CET.quarter
                  --Rank the data by total revenue within each group 
                         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                                (PARTITION BY  SALE_CET.quarter ORDER BY total_Revenue DESC
                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS ra
                  FROM SALE_CET
        )AS SALE_CET2
    )AS es
    WHERE 
         es.ra <=4
    ORDER BY 
         es.RevenueByItemThenByQuarter
```

Comment: Do you mean add another ROW_NUMBER() parallel with the existing one? Don't understand how it works. Could you provide the sample query code?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I believe the code works fine in the traditional database, but in Redshift, it yields to the same error. Whether I add the code "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING", it returns the error as : "Frame clause should not be specified for ranking window functions" / "Window function is not supported in order by clauses"

Comment: Doh! I just saw that your ra field was based on revenue. My answer does not apply to your question, sorry.

Comment: yea, I want to order the records by this sum() value field.